# Evaluation of $\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}^2u^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to evaluate the finite sum
\begin{equation}
f(u)=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}^2u^k,\quad 0<u\le1
\end{equation}

In an first attempt, I think of the generating function
\begin{equation}
(1+x)^n(u+x)^n = \sum_{k\ge0}{n\choose k}x^k\sum_{k\ge0}{n\choose k}u^kx^{n-k}=\cdots+x^n\sum_{k\ge0}{n\choose k}^2u^k+\cdots
\end{equation}

which means that $f(u)$ is the coefficients of the term $x^n$.

Expanding $(1+x)^n(u+x)^n$ into $[1+(1+u)x+x^2]^n$, and using the multinomial expansion, I get an expression for the coefficient of $x^n$. However, such an expression is more complicated than $f(u)$. It seems I am making the problem even more difficult.

Can someone help me find the value of $f(u)$.

Thank you.

Comment: $\sum a_i\sum b_i \neq \sum a_ib_i$! Rather, $=\sum a_ib_i+2\sum a_ib_j$

Comment: WRA found $f(x)=(1-x)^n\,P_n{\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}$, with $P_n$ being the $n$th Legendre polynomial of the first kind.

Comment: @DavidH Can you give more information, such as how is it derived?

Comment: @ecook Sure, see my response below.

Comment: See also: [Closed form for $S= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n x^k \binom{n}{k}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2138745)

Answer (score 4):

The Legendre polynomial $P_n$ happens to satisfy
$$P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 (x - 1)^{k}(x + 1)^{n-k}.$$
Hence
$$(1-x)^n P_n\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right) = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 (2x)^{k} 2^{n-k} =\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 x^k.$$

To prove the earlier equation, note that Rodrigues' formula gives
$$P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left((x^2 - 1)^n\right).$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
2^n P_n(x) 
  &= \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \left[\frac{d^k}{dx^k} (x - 1)^n\right] \left[\frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}} (x + 1)^n\right] \\
  &= \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}  \left[k! \binom{n}{k} (x - 1)^{n-k}\right] \left[(n-k)! \binom{n}{n-k} (x + 1)^k \right] \\
  &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 (x - 1)^{n-k} (x + 1)^k \\
  &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 (x - 1)^{k} (x + 1)^{n-k}.
\end{align*}

Comment: very impressive. thank you

Comment: @ecook No thanks necessary.

Comment: One more question. Do you have any idea of evaluating the generalized series $\sum_{k=0}^n{\alpha \choose k}^2$, where $\alpha$ is a non-integer?

Comment: Not off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\fermi\pars{u}\equiv\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}^{2}u^{k}:\ {\large ?}.
     \qquad 0\ <\ u\ \leq\ 1}$.

> \begin{align}
> \fermi\pars{u}&=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}u^{k}{n \choose n - k}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}u^{k}
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n - k + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n + 1}}
> \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{zu}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n + 1}}
> \,\pars{1 + zu}^{n}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
> {\bracks{uz^{2} + \pars{u + 1}z + 1}^{n} \over z^{n + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{a,b,c=0 \atop a + b + c=n}{n \choose a,b,c}u^{a}\pars{u + 1}^{b}
> \oint_{}{1 \over z^{n - 2a - b + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\left.%
> \sum_{a,b,c=0 \atop a + b + c=n}{n \choose a,b,c}u^{a}\pars{u + 1}^{b}\right\vert
> _{\,n\ -\ 2a\ -\ b\ =\ 0}
> =\sum_{c = 0}^{\floor{n/2}\atop}{n! \over \pars{n - 2c}!\,\pars{c!}^{2}}u^{c}\pars{u + 1}^{n - 2c}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#66f}{\large%
\fermi\pars{u}=
n!\,\pars{1 + u}^{n}\sum_{c = 0}^{\floor{n/2}\atop}{1 \over \pars{n - 2c}!\,\pars{c!}^{2}}\bracks{u \over \pars{1 + u}^{2}}^{c}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The $n$-th Legendre polynomial has the following representation as a finite series (ref. [Wolfram functions site](http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LegendreP/06/02/0002/)):

$$P_n{(z)}=\left(\frac{z-1}{2}\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^k.$$

Substituting $u=\frac{z+1}{z-1}=1+\frac{2}{z-1}$ into the above formula, yields:

$$P_n{\left(\frac{u+1}{u-1}\right)}=\frac{1}{(u-1)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2u^k.$$