# Binomial Coefficients Summation $\sum_{k=0}^n a^k \binom{n}{k}^2$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $a>0.$ Is there a closed form expression for the following summation:
$\sum_{k=0}^n a^k \binom{n}{k}^2$?

Comment: Well, according to Wolfram Alpha it is possible to express it in terms of Legendre polynomials. Do you consider this a closed form?

Comment: Could you please post the expression in terms of Legendre polynomials if possible ? Thanks!

Comment: For $a\neq 1$: $$\sum_{k=0}^n a^k \binom{n}{k}^2=(1-a)^n P_n\left(\frac{a+1}{1-a}\right)$$ For $a=1$: $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$$

Comment: Some related older posts: [Closed form for $S= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n x^k \binom{n}{k}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2138745) and [Evaluation of $\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}^2u^k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/912804). They can be found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En%20a%5Ek%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%5E2%24&p=1) or [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=$%7B%5Csum_%7Bk=0%7D%5En%20a%5Ek%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%5E2%7D$). See also: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: Thanks a lot! it answers my question.